# Delete a row from Telerik Radgrid. How I get Index of that selected Row?

Tags: telerik, radgrid, delete-row, itemdatabound, itemcommand

Here is the code I am using for delete functionality.

In RadgridItemdatabound funtion, I have to include this...

```
foreach (GridColumn col in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns)
                {
                    dataItem["TemplateDeleteColumn"].Attributes.Add("onclick","CellClick('" + dataItem.ItemIndex + "','" + col.UniqueName + "');");
                }
```

Then I have to create Itemcommand function.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteSelected")
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            var itemIndex = item.ItemIndex;
            string LoginId = item.GetDataKeyValue("LoginId").ToString();
            Int32 CampusCode = Convert.ToInt32(item.GetDataKeyValue("CampusCode"));


            Definations def = new Definations();
            Int32 Result = def.deleteUserAssignCampus(LoginId, CampusCode);
            if (Result == 1)
            {
                BindDeptDatasimple();

                cmbColumName.SelectedValue = "";
                cmbDirection.SelectedValue = "";
                Response.Redirect("UserCampus.aspx", false);
                Session["deleteUserCampus"] = "Campus dissociated successfully.";
            }
        }
    }
```

I could not get index of the selected row in the "var ItemIndex". 
It always return zero index in ItemIndex. That's why the first row from the grid gets deleted. How I can get selected Index of selected row?

Answer (score 0):

The item index will default to 0 because in your case you raise custom command 
through MasterTableView's client object method.

You will have to make sure that in your custom JS function, `CellClick`, item index is passed into `fireCommand` client method via the 2nd argument.

```
masterTable.fireCommand("DeleteSelected", itemIndex);
```

Then in `RadGrid1_ItemCommand` event handler, you can retrieve the index value like this

```
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
var itemIndex = e.CommandArgument;
```